# make regex not capture the OR capture group

Tags: php, regex

So, I am struggling to capture what kind of "language" snippet the string contains:

The language snippet are inside `()` and are combination of: `En,Fr,De,Es,It`

Example:

```
File (En,Fr,De,Es,It).doc    <== should match all 5 languages
File (En,Fr) (Required).doc  <== should match `En` and `Fr`
File (Enfoo,Fr).doc          <== should match only `Fr`
File (E,Fr).doc              <== should match only `Fr`
```

My current regex:

`((\(|,)En(\)|,))|((\(|,)Fr(\)|,))|((\(|,)De(\)|,))|((\(|,)Es(\)|,))|((\(|,)It(\)|,))`

What does it mean:

```
((\(|,)  <== either starts with `open parenthesis` or `comma`  (1)
En       <== the language                                      (2)
(\)|,))  <== either ends with `close parenthesis` or `comma`   (3)
```

then I just append with regex `OR` (|)

The problem as you can see: [regexr.com/3ev6p](http://regexr.com/3ev6p) is that if there is a second language snippet i.e. `Fr` it won't satisfy the regex `(1)` because the first language snippet `En` is capturing/occupying the `open parenthesis` or `comma` already, resulting for the 2nd language snippet `Fr` to be not matched...

[image]

Do you guys know how to handle completely capture all the language snippet? I am planning to use PHP's `preg_match_all()` to get all these. Hope somebody can help.
Thank you!

Comment: Not sure that i understand correctly, but is this what you want? https://regex101.com/r/PAwqGg/1

Comment: How about this http://regexr.com/3ev6s ?

Comment: @Mi-Creativity, boundaries should be arround all languages. ;)

Comment: @sinisake @Mi-Creativity Thank you its `\b` I was absent when they taught this at school. Thank you!

Comment: @sinisake that's true, in case he has this issue in all languages (words like *Enfoo*) , thanks for mentioning it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex you have consumes the commas around the language codes. That mean, after finding a match, the index is after a comma, and since there cannot be a match, the language after that comma is skipped by the regex engine.

In order to match such *overlapping* matches lookarounds can be used:

```
(?<=[(,])(En|Fr|De|Es|It)(?=[,)])
^^^^^^^^^                ^^^^^^^^
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/T0gBRg/1).

The `(?<=[(,])` is a positive lookbehind that requires a `,` or `(` before the language code, and `(?=[,)])` is a positive lookahead that requires a comma or `)` to the right of the language code, but the comma/parenthesis is not consumed, it remains to be matched during the next iteration.

Another solution that is possible here is the use of word boundaries (as is already described in the comments). Word boundaries help match *whole* words.

```
\b(En|Fr|De|Es|It)\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lDJPdA/1)

Comment: Woah, I do not also know about `positive lookbehind` nor `positive lookahead`. I should have not skipped school. Marked as answer for the additional explanation.

Answer (score 1):

This should match all:

```
 (?<=,|\()(\w\w)(?=,|\))
```

Accompanied by `preg_match_all` should do the job.

Explained:

- A lookbehind assertion (should be preceded by "," or "(")
- Two word characters (So you don't have to specify which languages you are targeting beforehand).
- A look ahead assertion (should be followed by "," or ")")

And thats it.

[Working version](https://regex101.com/r/3w5vY6/1).